# Java arrays: how to insert delete items in array 1D and 2D

Tags: java, arrays, insert, copy

I develop a GUI to manage 3D objects. For example PolyLine (multiple segments line linked) arrays of Point in Bezier Curve, 2D arrays of Point in Bezier surface, Double array 1D, Double array 2D.
I'd like to develop a class to insert/delete items on rows or columns in a single form with generic or something else.

here is my class file: (I don't think it works)

```
    package one.empty3.library.core;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by manue on 24-07-19.
 */
public class EcArrays<T>
{
    public T[] deleteRowAtDim1(T[] array, int pos)
    {
        T[] ts = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length-1);
        int i0=0;
        for(int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
            if(pos!=i)
            {
                ts[i] = array[i0];
                i0++;
            }
        }
        return ts;
    }
    public T[][] deleteRowAtDim2(T[][] array, int pos)
    {
        T[][] ts = (T[][]) new Object[array.length-1][];
        int i0=0;
        for(int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
            if(pos!=i)
            {
                ts[i] = array[i0];
                i0++;
            }
        }
        return ts;
    }
    public T[][] deleteColAtDim2(T[][] array, int pos)
    {
        T[][] ts = (T[][]) new Object[array.length][];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            ts[i] = deleteRowAtDim1(array[i], pos);
        }
        return ts;
    }

    T[] insertRowAtDim1(T[] array, int pos, T value)
    {
        T[] ts = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length+1);
        int i0=0;
        for(int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
            if(pos!=i)
            {
                ts[i] = array[i0];
                i0++;
            }
            else {
                ts[i] = value;
            }
        }
        return ts;
    }
    public T[][] insertRowAtDim2(T[][] array, int pos, int rowSize)
    {
        T[][] ts = (T[][]) new Object[array.length+1][];
        int i0= 0;
        for(int i=0; i<ts.length;i++)
        {
            if(i!=pos) {
                ts[i] = array[i0];
                i0++;
            }
            else {
                ts[i] = (T[]) new Object[rowSize];
            }
        }
        return ts;
    }
    public T[][] insertColAtDim2(T[][] array, int pos)
    {
        T[][] ts = (T[][]) new Object[array.length][];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            ts[i] = insertRowAtDim1(array[i], pos, (T) new Object());
        }
        return ts;
    }

}
```

I tried multiple method for different array object class

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? How have you tested it / run it? What error did you get?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Graphics3D/Empty3/blob/master/src/test/java/test3/EcArraysTest.java  Yes, it's ok now. https://gitlab.com/Graphics3D/Empty3/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fone%2Fempty3%2Flibrary%2Fcore%2FEcArrays.java

Answer (score 1):

According to your scenario you can use collections like  class like [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) where dynamically you can insert or remove elements. According to your case you can initialize your structure like this below:

```
List<List<T>> dynamicMatrix2D = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
```

Every element of the `ArrayList` represents one of your rows (initially empty) where you can add or remove your elements.